# How to create a html collection of elements located in separate divs

Tags: javascript

I need to create a html collection containing five input-elements, with type = text.

The html:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <label><input type="checkbox" align="middle">
        <img src="lorem.jpg" alt="img 1" class="image">
    </label>
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <label>Lorem<input type="text" value="lorem"></label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

When I do this, I get a collection with all the input-elements, I only want the ones that has the value = text.

```
innerDivTag = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

And when I do this, I get five separate collections and that is not my aim.

```
for (i = 0; i < outerDiv.length; i++) {
  innerDivTag = innerBox[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine besides for the fact that it only returned one of the input elements (the first one)

Comment: Yes, i made the change in my answer - initially I made a mistake by using `querySelector` - use `querySelectorAll` instead

Comment: Just realized that this wasn´t what I needed. Turns out querySelectorAll is not live and therefore dosen't changes to the DOM.